# Getting error on running a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have an error running this statement in vb.net.The following error
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Request.GodownFROM Request WHERE (((Request.Rdate)=#03/27/2017#) AND ((Request.Godown)='Indian''.

```
sql = "SELECT Request.[Rdate], Request.[Item Name], Request.[Category], Request.[Unit], Request.[Quantity], Request.[Rate], Request.[Amount], Request.[Godown]" _
          & "FROM Request WHERE Request.[Rdate]=#" & dtrdate.Value & "# AND Request.[Godown]='" & lblgodown.Text & "'"

    Dim da As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)

    da.Fill(dt)
    dgtvgo1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space before the "[from...]". So change the second line to " [from..."

Comment: Hi Dave, if you feel the question is wrong only in having a small typo, then vote to close the question rather than answering it.

Comment: Thanks, I know this will be a small mistake somewhere. I have encounter the same problem before and solved it the same way. But somehow I missed this time.

Comment: Tim - seroiously?  Close the question rather than helping the person with an answer?  I will never understand the protocol on this site.